# Having trouble with coding bat warm up: max1020

Tags: java

Can anyone help me with this Coding Bat question, I got pretty close but I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I tried to rework my code in different ways and looked at the solution. If anyone can explain the issue that will be great. I am very new to coding and Java so I'm sorry if the solution is obvious. This is the question.

Given 2 positive int values, return the larger value that is in the range 10..20 inclusive, or return 0 if neither is in that range.

```
max1020(11, 19) → 19

max1020(19, 11) → 19

max1020(11, 9) → 11
```

and this is my code:

```
public int max1020(int a, int b) {
    int max = 0;
    if(a>b){
      max = a;
    }else{
      max = b;
    }
   if((a<=20  &&  a>=10)||(b<=20 && b>=10)){
     return max;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

these are the results.

```
Expected    Run     
max1020(11, 19) → 19    19  OK  
max1020(19, 11) → 19    19  OK  
max1020(11, 9) → 11 11  OK  
max1020(9, 21) → 0  0   OK  
max1020(10, 21) → 10    21  X   
max1020(21, 10) → 10    21  X   
max1020(9, 11) → 11 11  OK  
max1020(23, 10) → 10    23  X   
max1020(20, 10) → 20    20  OK  
max1020(7, 20) → 20 20  OK  
max1020(17, 16) → 17    17  OK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by implementing the test harness you have posted, that is a **very** useful capability in correctly implementing any algorithm.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][][] testCases = { { { 11, 19 }, { 19 } }, //
            { { 19, 11 }, { 19 } }, //
            { { 11, 9 }, { 11 } }, //
            { { 9, 21 }, { 0 } }, //
            { { 10, 21 }, { 10 } }, //
            { { 21, 10 }, { 10 } }, //
            { { 9, 11 }, { 11 } }, //
            { { 23, 10 }, { 10 } }, //
            { { 20, 10 }, { 20 } }, //
            { { 7, 20 }, { 20 } }, //
            { { 17, 16 }, { 17 } } };
    for (int i = 0; i < testCases.length; i++) {
        int a = testCases[i][0][0], b = testCases[i][0][1], c = testCases[i][1][0];
        int r = max1020(a, b);
        System.out.printf("max1020(%d, %d) -> %d   %d %s%n", a, b, r, c, 
                c == r ? "OK" : "X");
    }
}
```

Then I would implement `max1020` by first validating whether `a` and `b` are in the *required range*. And I would save the results of that validation in local `boolean` variables. If both are in range, you want the maximum of the two. If only one is in range you want that value, and if neither is in range zero. Like,

```
public static int max1020(int a, int b) {
    boolean aRange = a >= 10 && a <= 20, bRange = b >= 10 && b <= 20;
    if (aRange && bRange) {
        return Math.max(a, b);
    } else if (!aRange && bRange) {
        return b;
    } else if (aRange) { // !bRange implied by last two tests
        return a;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which outputs (with the test harness)

```
max1020(11, 19) -> 19   19 OK
max1020(19, 11) -> 19   19 OK
max1020(11, 9) -> 11   11 OK
max1020(9, 21) -> 0   0 OK
max1020(10, 21) -> 10   10 OK
max1020(21, 10) -> 10   10 OK
max1020(9, 11) -> 11   11 OK
max1020(23, 10) -> 10   10 OK
max1020(20, 10) -> 20   20 OK
max1020(7, 20) -> 20   20 OK
max1020(17, 16) -> 17   17 OK
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are returning the max value if one of the 2 values are in the range, and you're suposed to return the max value of the values that are in the range.

That is, between 10 and 21, return 10 because 21, despite is bigger, is out of range.

You may change your function as this:

```
public int max1020(int a, int b) {
    int max = 0;
    if(a <= 20  &&  a >= 10){
      max = a;
    } 
    if (b > max && (b <= 20 && b >= 10)){
      max = b;
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: This may not work. You can test it here  https://codingbat.com/prob/p177372

Comment: You don't see the link? Interesting!

Comment: Well, I see it now!

Comment: @pdrersin yes! I fixed my BUGS

Comment: @viktor234 I very rencently fixed some bugs, may be now works

Comment: And the above fix  should also do it.

Answer (score 1):

You first seem to figure out the `max`. And then -

```
 if((a<=20  &&  a>=10)||(b<=20 && b>=10)){
   return max;
 }
```

The above piece of code returns `max` irrespective of whether the `max` is actually in the range or not.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
public int max1020(int a, int b) {
  return ((a>=10 && a<=20) && (b>=10 && b<=20))?(b>a?b:a)
  :(a>=10 && a<=20)?a
  :(b>=10 && b<=20)?b
  :0;
}
```

Comment: Quad nested ternaries (oh my)!